# Create folder and Folder not found

Tags: dart, flutter

I just try to create folder follow this code

```
io.Directory appDocDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
new io.Directory(appDocDirectory.path + '/' + 'dir').create(recursive: true)
  // The created directory is returned as a Future.
    .then((io.Directory directory) {
  print('Path of New Dir: ' + directory.path);
});
```

and the result of this is

> I/flutter (32540): Path of New Dir:
>   /data/user/0/[Package_name]/app_flutter/dir.

I am using real device and I don't have SdCard. 
I can't find this folder. how I solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking at `directory.path` very likely before the future (from `.then`) has completed. You've got the right idea using `await` earlier.  Just do that again.